# What is the difference between Send Message and Post Message and how these relate to C# ,WPF and Pure windows programming?

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi

What is the difference between Send Message and Post Message ( in terms of pure windows programming) and how these relate to C# ,WPF and Pure windows programming?

I am new to Threading and all related stuff so please excuse me for obvious quesiton .
I need to dig out the externals of Threading .. Please let me know the links that help me to build my concept from win32 programming to WPF.

I need to underderstand from Post message to Afx ( call to start a new thread ) to delegate Invok/Begin Invoke to Dispatcher.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

`PostMessage` (in "pure windows programming", aka win32 API) is [asynchronous](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644944(VS.85).aspx), i.e., to quote the docs:

> Places (posts) a message in the
>   message queue associated with the
>   thread that created the specified
>   window and returns without waiting for
>   the thread to process the message.
>
> To post a message in the message queue
>   associated with a thread, use the
>   PostThreadMessage function.

`SendMessage` is [synchronous](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950(VS.85).aspx), that is, again quoting:

> Sends the specified message to a
>   window or windows. The SendMessage
>   function calls the window procedure
>   for the specified window and does not
>   return until the window procedure has
>   processed the message.
>
> To send a message and return
>   immediately, use the
>   SendMessageCallback or
>   SendNotifyMessage function. To post a
>   message to a thread's message queue
>   and return immediately, use the
>   PostMessage or PostThreadMessage
>   function.

A good tutorial on these two functions and their use is [here](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/SendMessage.htm).

The connection to WPF is discussed in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411116/equivalent-of-postmessage-in-c-to-synchronize-with-the-main-thread-with-mvvm).