# Call SendMessage throwing a runtime error

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to pass text to a 3rd party program but running into a snag.

I have isolated the Class Handler ID inside my program,validated with the messagebox. However, when I try sending it text, I get a run time error.

```
Public Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32.dll" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Int32
Public Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32.dll" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Int32, ByVal wMsg As Int32, ByVal wParam As Int32, ByVal lParam As Int32) As Int32
Public Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32.dll" Alias "FindWindowExA" (ByVal hWnd1 As Int32, ByVal hWnd2 As Int32, ByVal lpsz1 As String, ByVal lpsz2 As String) As Int32

Dim hwnd As Integer
Dim hwindow2 As Integer
Dim main_view As Integer
Dim sub_window As Integer
Public Const WM_SETTEXT = &H0
```

And

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
hwindow2 = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Trace")
main_view = FindWindowEx(hwindow2, 0&, "#32770", vbNullString)
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10)
sub_window = FindWindowEx(main_view, 0&, "Edit", vbNullString)
MessageBox.Show(main_view)
MessageBox.Show(sub_window)
Call SendMessage(sub_window, WM_SETTEXT, 0, "test")
End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: If only there was some way for us to know what that run-time error was.

Comment: That said, I'm fairly sure that the value of the `WM_SETTEXT` message is not zero.  You might want to look that up.

Comment: have you checked the 3rd party documentation?

Answer (score -1):

you might consider using PostMessage(), it is an asynchronous method and it won't wait for the response from the receiving end. while SendMessage method is synchronous, it 'does not return until the window procedure has processed the message'.
see suggestions from post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3376619/what-is-the-difference-between-send-message-and-post-message-and-how-these-relat)

it is also good to indicate the error message to better understand the problem.